# Merge or Commit to two separate repositories

Tags: linux, git, repository

Currently we have repo cos which is our main repo. We also have repo cos2 which contained all of cos's commits up to the date we forked. They are completely separate repos. We will need to commit changes in cos to cos2 until we officially move to cos2, but we need the commits from cos in cos2 during the interim.

```
Repo Cos   A---B---C---D---n
               |   |   |   |
Repo Cos2  A---B---C---D---n
```

or

```
Repo Cos   A---B---C---D---n
             \   \   \   \
Repo Cos2  E---F---G---H---n
```

How do we get specific commits or merges in cos over to cos2?

Nothing in cos2 will ever need to go to cos, but everything in cos will need to go to cos2. However, we need to be able to continue development in cos2 so we can't just clone cos to recreate cos2 as divergence happens.

I was hoping there was a command like,

```
git merge feature/branch user@giturl:/cos2 :feature/branch
```

but I don't think that exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your default repository as a second server to your cos2 repository using the command:

```
git remote add COS ssh://user@serverurl:cos.git
```

After that you can merge the COS master branch to your current cos2 branch:

```
git merge COS/master
```

This way you can easily pull commits from cos to cos2.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I just recently found this in the git docs. `http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#Checking-Out-Remote-Branches`. It confirms what you've said above. Thanks for the answer.